# Coordinate transformation and line element

Tags: derivatives, coordinate-systems, transformation, chain-rule

I am going over a question, for which I know the answer, but I could not figure out how to get to that.

I am given the line element
$ds^2=dx^2-dy^2=dudv$
and I must find the coordinate transformation $u=u(x,y)$ and $v=v(x,y)$.

The answers are $u=x-y$ and $v=y+x$.

I tried with derivatives and using the chain rule, but I was not able to get to the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious relations
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=1\,,\quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-1\,,\quad\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=1\,,\quad\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=1
$$
give (using the chain rule) that
$$
\frac{du}{dx}=1-\frac{dy}{dx}\,,\quad\frac{du}{dy}=\frac{dx}{dy}-1\,,\quad\frac{dv}{dx}=1+\frac{dy}{dx}\,,\quad\frac{dv}{dy}=\frac{dx}{dy}+1
$$
hold.

These relations can be written as
$$
du=dx-dy\,,\quad dv=dx+dy\,,\quad\text{ or, }\quad dx=\frac{du+dv}{2}\,,\quad dy=\frac{dv-du}{2}\,.
$$
Therefore,
$$
ds^2=dx^2-dy^2=du\,dv\,.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the thing is that the answer is not given beforehand, so I cannot use it to go backwards into the line element.

Comment: @Zvhvh55 . We have verified that $x,y$ and $u,v$ lead to the same line element. What does it mean that you "cannot use it to go backwards into the line element" ? Sounds like you want a hint how to solve it differently: Try $ds^2=dx^2-dy^2=(dx+dy)(dx-dy)$. Does that look familiar? You want $dv=dx+dy$ and $du=dx-dy$. You see it?

Comment: Now I get it thank you!